# Switching application using Citrix ICA client connected via laptop

Tags: citrix, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using the Citrix online plugin (ICA) to connect remotely to the machines located outside our premises. Now most of the keyboard shortcuts work, but the replacement of <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> does not work. I have tried both <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>[Plus]</kbd>/<kbd>[Minus]</kbd>, but both of them do not work.

I am using the Toshiba Satellite L510 laptop. Now the <kbd>+</kbd> key is accessible only after pressing shift, i.e, it is on the top of <kbd>=</kbd>. So I also tried <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>[PLUS]</kbd>, but it does not work.

If anybody can help me, how can I switch between applications while connected to the remote machine using the Citrix ICA client, from a Toshiba Satellite laptop?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the way your windows key combination behave in the Program neighborhood agent properties, session option tab.

There's a list letting you choose if you want your windows key to be applied to your local desktop, remote desktop, or full screen desktops only.

(You need to change the setting Before launching an ICA for this to work.)

Comment: How is "Program neighborhood agent" invoked?

Answer (score 2):

It works for me when I use the Plus/Minus keys from the numpad.

Also to switch between applications, you can try <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to cycle through all the open applications one by one.

Answer (score 1):

I got this finally after struggling a lot.

Go to regedit and use ctrl+f to find TransparentKeypassthrough, Wherever you find the value blank, change it to Remote. it will definitely work. But do not change if the value is numeric.